# Spring Boot - Request method 'POST' not supported to upload file

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

Front: Angular2+
Back: Java15 Spring Boot
DataBase: MySql

I take all examples for upload files in database form in byte[]. with a complex object with file by attribute.

I try desperately to upload an image file on my database so I try to create post API rest by I have error

I'm take

```
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported
```

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/Ninja/image/")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> saveNinjaImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String message = "";
        try {
            Iterable<Syndic> lstN= NinjaRepository.findAll();
            if(lstN.iterator().hasNext()) {
                Ninja s = lstN.iterator().next();
                s.setPicture(file.getBytes());
                logger.info(s.toString());
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
            logger.info(e.toString());
        }
        return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
    }
```

```js
//service
  public postNinja(file: File) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    
    formData.append('file', file);

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `${this.host}/Ninja/image`, formData, {
      headers: this.headers,
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'json'
    });

    return this.http.request(req);
  }
/* ts */
public onSave() {
  this.frontDynamic.submitted = true;
  if (this.frontDynamic.updateNinja.invalid) {
    return;
  } else {
    const formValue = this.frontDynamic.updateNinja.value;
    const newNinja = new Ninja(formValue['nom']);
    newNinja.address = formValue['adresse'];
    newNinja.description = formValue['description'];
    newNinja.website = formValue['site'];
    this.ninjaService.putNinja(newNinja,formValue['image']).subscribe(response => {},
 error => {console.log(error);}
,
        ()=>{
          this.ninjaService.postNinja(formValue['image']).subscribe(
            event => {},
            err => {});
);

  }
}
```

Comment: Your mapping value is `/Ninja/image/`.  It looks like the javascript is posting to `/Syndic/Image`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: sorry it's fixed but it's not that the problem